# CodeIgniter: how to configure to connect to a different DB?

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

Currently, I have my database configuration something like this:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "my_username";
$db['default']['password'] = "my_password";
```

I actually want to connect to a different MySQL database hosted on a different server. Where would I find the hostname I need to use? Is there anything else I need to do besides changing the hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an array of arrays, and always explicitly index them as needed:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "foo";
$db['default']['password'] = bar";
$db['default']['database'] = "blablabla";

$db['development']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['development']['username'] = "boo";
$db['development']['password'] = "par";
$db['development']['database'] = "blablabladev";

$this->dbdev = $this->load->database('development', TRUE);
```

Comment: my question was how to reference an external MySQL DB. in other words, what do I replace "localhost" with?

Comment: Just put the IP address in or the domain: example.domain.com. Just no HTTP, since it's not using that protocol.

Comment: exactly as jpea mentioned, use the IP address (ex: 123.45.67.89)

Answer (score 0):

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "new.host.name.com";
```

Also make sure that mysql on your new.host.name.com will accept external connection, by providing your localhost IP

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you'll be able to get this information from the same place you created the database. So if you used a control panel on your web host to create the database, it's likely you will be able to find the address by looking around the control panel's MySql section.

Some web hosts don't allow remote access to the database either, so be wary of that.

To answer your second question, yes, you will likely have to change the username and password, the new values should also be found in the area where you created the database.

Apologies if this is a very generic answer.